# highcharts drilldown not working

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Highcharts drilldown is not working . Scenario is From graph, if i click any point It needs to show another graph using avgTimes.testIds (check below json). But i am unable to get testId value when i click on the point. 
Please check Json and Javascript for reference .

"this.series.data.indexOf( this.point )" code is not working to get the indexValue, it is giving "undefined" as response.Please check javascript code

Response json Json:

```
{
  "testid": {
    "name": "testId",
    "data": [
      208,
      207,
      206,
      205,
      202
    ]
  },
  "xaxis": {
    "xaxis": "xaxis",
    "data": [
      "2016/03/21  01:50:04",
      "2016/03/20  04:56:20",
      "2016/03/20  04:41:56",
      "2016/03/18  11:09:53",
      "2016/03/18  09:33:15"
    ]
  },
  "avgTimes": {
    "name": "avgTime",
    "units": "ms",
    "data": [
      1894,
      3141,
      44966,
      1792,
      22929
    ],
    "testIds": [
      208,
      207,
      206,
      205,
      202
    ]
  }
}
```

Below is the javascript which i am using

```js
 var options;
  var chart;
  $(document).ready(function() {
        init();
        
   });  
   
   function init() {
     $('#back_btn').hide();
     options = {
       chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'line',
                zoomType: 'x',
            },
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: ''
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: [],
                
                labels: {
     align: 'center',
     x: -3,
     y: 20,
     formatter: function() {
      return Highcharts.dateFormat('%b-%d', Date.parse(this.value));
     }
    }
    
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: ''
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                enabled: true,
                formatter: function() {
                    return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                       '<b>'+ this.x +': '+ this.y+'  '+'</b><br/>'+
                        'TestId: '+this.series.options.testIds[this.series.data.indexOf(this.point)];

                        
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                line: {
                 cursor: 'pointer',
                    point: {
                        events: {
                            click: function() {
                             
                                

                                //document.write(this.series.options.testIds[this.series.data.indexOf( this.point )]);
                             $('#dateDisplay').text(this.series.options.testIds[this.series.data.indexOf( this.point )]);
                             
                             $.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/reports/graph/transaction?testId="+this.series.options.testIds[this.series.data.indexOf( this.point )], function(json){
                              
               options.xAxis.categories = json.xAxis.xaxisList;
                                    options.series[0] = json.avgTimes;
                                    options.series[1] = json.tps;
                                    options.series[2] = json.minTimes;
                                    options.series[3] = json.maxTimes;
               options.xAxis.labels = {
                formatter: function() {
          //return Highcharts.dateFormat('%l%p', Date.parse(this.value +' UTC'));
          return Highcharts.dateFormat('%l%p', Date.parse(this.value));
          //return this.value;
          }
               }
               
               options = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
               
               $('#back_btn').show();
               
              });

        
                         }
                        }
                    },
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true
                    }
                }
            },

            series: [{
                 type: 'line',
                 name: '',
                 data: []
        }]
  }

        $.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/reports/graph/tests?limit=10&offset=1&env=stg&project=MarketplaceOffers&userCount=10", function(json){
         options.xAxis.categories = json.xaxis.data;
                options.series[0]= json.avgTimes;
                //options.series[1]=json.testid;
                //options.series[1].extra= json.testid;
                

                chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
  });
 }
   
    
    function goback() {
     init();
     $('#dateDisplay').text("2013-02");
 }
```

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head> 
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/> 
 <title>Dynamic Drill Down in Highcharts</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
  <style>
   body,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,ul,ol,dl,input,textarea { font-family: 'Lucida Grande', Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif; }  
  </style>
  
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="date.js"></script>
  <script src="dynamicChats.js"></script>
 </head>
<body>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<strong><div id="dateDisplay">2013-02</div></strong>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

<a href="#" onclick="goback();" id="back_btn">Back</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you know at which line it fails? you have mentioned that it fails at `this.series.data.indexOf( this.point )`, but you have it thrice in your code.

Comment: .getJSON("http://localhost:8080/reports/graph/transaction?testId="+this.series.options.testIds[this.series.data.indexOf( this.point )]

Comment: that's weird, that it works in the line before but not in the getJSON call. Can you add `var index = this.series.data.indexOf( this.point )` as the first line of your click callback and use it where you need it (basically where it is failing, the getJSON call)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this.point` is undefined that's why you can't retrieve the index from this.series.data array. It seems that when a point is clicked on the graph, `this` refers to the point object itself in the click handler.

You should replace the line bellow :

`this.series.options.testIds[this.series.data.indexOf(this.point)]`

by this one :

`this.series.options.testIds[this.series.data.indexOf(this)]`

I also moved the creation of the object `options` inside the getJSON callback function :

```
<script>
    var chart;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        init();
    });

    function init() {
        $('#back_btn').hide();

        $.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/reports/graph/tests?limit=10&offset=1&env=stg&project=MarketplaceOffers&userCount=10", function (json) {


            var options = {
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container',
                    type: 'line',
                    zoomType: 'x',
                },
                title: {
                    text: ''
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: ''
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: [],

                    labels: {
                        align: 'center',
                        x: -3,
                        y: 20,
                        formatter: function () {
                            return Highcharts.dateFormat('%b-%d', Date.parse(this.value));
                        }
                    }
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: ''
                    }
                },
                tooltip: {
                    enabled: true,
                    formatter: function () {
                        return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
                           '<b>' + this.x + ': ' + this.y + '  ' + '</b><br/>' +
                            'TestId: ' + this.series.options.testIds[this.series.data.indexOf(this.point)];
                    }
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    line: {
                        cursor: 'pointer',
                        point: {
                            events: {
                                click: function () {
                                    //document.write(this.series.options.testIds[this.series.data.indexOf( this.point )]);
                                    $('#dateDisplay').text(this.series.options.testIds[this.series.data.indexOf(this.point)]);
                                    $.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/reports/graph/transaction?testId=" + this.series.options.testIds[this.series.data.indexOf(this)], function (json) {

                                        options.xAxis.categories = json.xAxis.xaxisList;
                                        options.series[0] = json.avgTimes;
                                        options.series[1] = json.tps;
                                        options.series[2] = json.minTimes;
                                        options.series[3] = json.maxTimes;
                                        options.xAxis.labels = {
                                            formatter: function () {
                                                //return Highcharts.dateFormat('%l%p', Date.parse(this.value +' UTC'));
                                                return Highcharts.dateFormat('%l%p', Date.parse(this.value));
                                                //return this.value;
                                            }
                                        }

                                        options = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
                                        $('#back_btn').show();
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: true
                        }
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    type: 'line',
                    name: '',
                    data: []
                }]
            };


            options.xAxis.categories = json.xaxis.data;
            options.series[0] = json.avgTimes;
            chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
        });
    }


    function goback() {
        init();
        $('#dateDisplay').text("2013-02");
    }

</script>
```